# Choose the design resolution size for Android devices in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm having trouble when trying to choose design resolution sizes for Android devices.

I just want to have around 4-5 resources (images, background, sprites, etc) but can run in any Android devices. What the suitable design resolution I can do? For example, 320x480, 720x1280, what else?

Can you give me some advice to choose?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In your AppDelegate class:
```

this resolution is for Landscape Mode

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{

    /**********************  CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize() //set design resolution size and mode
     *********************  CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->getFrameSize() //get screen resolution
     *********************CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize() //get design resolution
     *********************  CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize() //get design resolution’s visable area size
     *********************  CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin() //get origin of the visable area of design resolution*/


    // initialize director
    CCDirector* director = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    CCEGLView* EGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

    director->setOpenGLView(EGLView);


    CCSize screenSize = EGLView->getFrameSize();
    CCSize designSize = CCSizeMake(1024,614);
    EGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width,designSize.height, kResolutionExactFit);


    CCLog("Screen Size:%f %f",screenSize.width,screenSize.height);


    if(screenSize.height >= 320 && screenSize.height <= 480)
    {
        CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(800, 480);
        director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
        CCLog("Resolution Scale OF Default =%f",resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);

    }


    else if(screenSize.height >= 540 && screenSize.height < 720 )
    {

        CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(960, 540);
        director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
        CCLog("Resolution Scale OF Karboon=%f",resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
    }


    else if (screenSize.height >= 720 && screenSize.height < 800)
    {

        CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1280, 720);
        director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
        CCLog("Resolution Scale OF NOTE=%f",resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);

    }

    else if(screenSize.height > 800)
    {
        CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1920, 1080);
        director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
        CCLog("Resolution Scale OF Nexus=%f",resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);

    }

    else
    {


        director->setContentScaleFactor(1);
        CCLog("Resolution Scale OF S Advance=%f");

    }
```

Comment: I want the example for the design resolution such as 320x480, 720x1280, what else?

Comment: In the above code i am using 1024x614 resolution resources. SO, if you want this resolution should work in every android device you can use the above code.

Comment: Maybe, you misunderstood my question. I don't need code, I just need which size resolution which I can use for design resolution to make sprites, images, etc to fit the screen size for all Android devices? For example, I'm going to create 320x460, 720x1280 images, background, what else?

Comment: if you are developing a good  graphics game then you can use 1024x614 resolution.

Comment: Now, I'm using 1280x720 resolution. Is it ok?

Comment: How did you the correct values per screen sizes? Is there a table for it?

Comment: See, the above code will work for every screen size there is no table for the screen sizes.